# IE11 Not enough storage to complete this operation

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

I'm currently developping on Outlook2016 Add-in with the goal to download an email as eml file and upload it to another service.

The problem is the add-in is running in a 32bit IE11 process and when I'm fetching the email (with attachments included) as base64string and the totalsize is bigger then 6-7MB I cannot parse the response and IE11 throws a 'Not enough storage to complete this operation' error.

I can't even use a breakpoint or console.log the response, each attempt to interact with it results in this error.

Anyone an idea ?

Comment: Try checking Tools>Internet Options>General tab Browsing History section, Parameters button and caches and databases tab, there is a size cache limitation. Maybe this will make things go better if you change it...

Comment: Already tried that, it is set to 1024mB, hasn't changed a thing.

Comment: I suggest you to try to restart your machine and again try to check for the issue. Other thing, you can try to check How much memory consumed by that IE tab. Also check whether it is any machine specific issue.

Comment: Restarted the machine multiple times after tying out some things (activated enhanced protected mode, forced IE in EPM to use 64 bit process,...), cleaned the cache. I tried taking memory snapshots in the F12 devtools, but as soon as it is receiving the payload I cannot take a snapshot anymore (Error not enough memory). Memory using is around 150MB before I receive the payload, then it goes up to 350MB and throws the error. [Here](https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-javascript-api/issues/329#issuecomment-559069203) is a link to where I initially raised the error.

Comment: Does the same error occur if you try to run on any other machine? If you did not checked it then you can check it may help to know whether it is machine specific issue or not.

Comment: Yes its happening on all 4 machines I tested. From what I have read IE11 32 bit should be able to handle up to 1.4 GB of memory, I do not understand where this error is comming from.

Comment: Since you are uploading the attachment to another service anyways, have you considered having your service pull the attachment directly from Exchange (instead of going through the client)?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54412828/how-to-use-rest-to-download-outlook-attachments-from-a-node-server or for EWS -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item.  Also, in case it helps, for more recent Windows and Office versions, Edge based control is used in the add-in, and Edge handles larger JavaScript object better than the IE process.

Comment: I solved my problem by having a small server that gets the ids from the client and uses `ews-javascript-api` to download the attachments. Not a real nice solution but given the limitations...